# Constraint exceptions after dropping Unique Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, unique-constraint

We had a Unique Constraint UQ_EMP_PROC_ID on the table Employee on the columns System_id (FK to table System) and Process_id.

Due to Unique Constraint Exceptions, we dropped this constraint. But then, the exceptions are still there with the same name UQ_EMP_PROC_ID. We also double checked, and the constraint has been dropped. We could also see an index which has been created on the Unique constraint of the same name (not dropped). Can this be the issue? If so why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is required.

Note: Using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Did the constraint name exists in user_constraints

Comment: Yes. we had deleted from user_constraints.But we could see same constraint name with different owners in all_constraints.

Comment: It might be created on different schema. constraints can be of same name with different name. Check the Owner field in all_constraints

Comment: To drop a constraint you should use the `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` command. I'm surprised that it was possible to delete from the USER_CONSTRAINTS view, if that's what you actually did. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis We had deleted from the USER_CONSTRAINTS, using the ALTER TABLE script. But if it is still throwing exception, what could be the possible reason? The same constraint exists under different owners in the db

Comment: @BobJarvis And Would constraints with the same name on the same table on other schema's cause an issue?

Comment: It seems to me that this is why you're still getting constraint violations. I didn't know that multiple constraints could be created with the same name but in different schemas. I guess that all the like-named constraints will need to be dropped, or at least disabled.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue with Oracle DB recently. @Chillax, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the index and recreating it without the unique contraint. Even though the contraint itself was dropped, the index may still be holding onto it.

This can be seen in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes006.htm "To drop a constraints associated index, you must disable or drop the constraint itself."